# Android on Sony Ericsson - Showing aspx page as source

Tags: .net, asp.net, android, cross-browser

When I visit my aspx page on an android phone instead of the page I get the website source.

It did not used to do this, I'm wondering if there is a known issue here.

Comment: is it the html or the asp source it is showing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing .aspx source, it appears your webserver is misconfigured. Are you sure you're using the same url on your Android device as in the browser?

If you're seeing the HTML source, it's probably the content-type of the page that's unknown to your Android browser. Which browser are you using? Can you browse other sites?

Comment: Its the default browser that comes with android.

Comment: Also its the html source that is displayed AND my friends android phone with the default browser copes fine.

Comment: Is your browser able to open all the other pages?

Comment: Yes, have looked at other ASP.NET pages too.

Comment: Is your page modifying the content type? If your friends phones are working, I think it's same to assume the problem is with your Android browser...